# Getting the id from the route in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made a modal on from the previous page, but the modal itself is in different page from the first page I declared the id in uploading image which is 1490

```
openUpload(id) {
        const {router} = this.context;
        let path = router.getCurrentLocation().pathname
        this.setState({upload: true});
        router.push(`${path}/upload/`+id)
    }
```

My problem is how will I pass the id on the modal itself page?

[image]

Comment: can you explain more, not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MayankShukla I have the webpage for all the things inside the page and it linked to the modal upload the code above yet the modal have its own code on different jsx file and i want to pass the id from the page to another by using its route or anything else... i just need to get the 1490 and the 1068

Comment: How about you make the modal as a component itself then pass the id as props to it?

Comment: It's probably simplest to just split the path and take those values from it then pass it the modal as props as mentioned above. You may want to use some kind of url parsing library though it's not necessary if your app is actually predictable (by that I mean the id's will always be in indexes 2 and 4 if you split on `/`). If those value may or may not be there, you just need to add error handling around the parse/split of the path.